# SetHidden not working

Tags: cocoa

I am developing an application in cocoa.I need to hide a progress bar placed in an NSView 
and show an NSTextfield in that place .I used the following cod
[progressbar setHidden:TRUE]
[textfield setHidden:FALSE];
But this code snippet is not working. Is that a bug.??I used to hide the same code to hide certain other text fields in the same page .But that controls became hidden.looking for a solution...

Answer (score 8):

Are ***progressbar*** and ***textfield*** outlets ? If yes, make sure they are correctly connected in your nib. Also make sure that you call setHidden: from the main thread.

And unrelated to your problem, in Objective-C you should use *YES* instead of *TRUE* and *NO* instead of *FALSE*.